# Is it possible to show a JPanel without putting it in a JFrame? Or full screen GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

Okay this is probably a rookie question, but I have never done GUI programming in Java before.  Is it possible to use a JPanel that is not in a JFrame? or essentially create a GUI that does not have the system Max, Min, Close buttons or a border?

If that seems confusing please let me know and I will be more clear with what I am trying to accomplish (I might be going about it all wrong);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `JWindow` instead of a `JFrame`.

Comment: Thank you JWindow is exactly what I need.  I wasn't even aware of its existence.

Comment: Can we make Jpanel visible without using any other component

Comment: @AmitRai no; `JPanel` is not a root level component. See [documentation of JRootPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html) for details.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `jFrame.setUndecorated(true);`

Comment: ok, you bet me to it)) but yeah this is exactly how you get rid of the decorations. Also you can construct your own JDialog (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you don't need a JPanel inside of a JFrame.  You should take a look at this article: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html